# Now that apt-key is deprecated, how do you add an Ubuntu PPA as a Debian APT source?

Tags: debian, apt, gpg, ppa, apt-key

### Background

In the past, if you wanted to install software from an Ubuntu PPA in Debian, the approach was to

1. import/trust the developer's GPG key from keyserver.ubuntu.com,

   ```bsh
   $ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com E58A9D36647CAE7F
   ```
2. then add the repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/...`

   ```bsh
   # /etc/apt/sources.list.d/papirus-ppa.list
   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu focal main
   ```

(Off the top of my head, examples can be found in [this Ubuntu docs wiki for mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/install-to-debian) or [the Papirus icon theme readme](https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme).)

### Problem

The problem is that **this approach now produces deprecation warnings** (`apt-key` was deprecated [over a year ago](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/11625)):

```
$ apt-key adv ...
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8))
```

> #### Ninja edit
>
> See [this answer below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679498/176219) for yet another, separate deprecation in this `apt-key` command!

### Solution?

The new approach (as exemplified by, say, [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-repository)) is twofold:

1. Save the developer's GPG key to disk,

   ```bsh
   $ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
   ```
2. then specify the path to that GPG key when defining a new APT source:

   ```bsh
   # /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
   deb [... signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable
            ⬑------------------ this part is new -----------------⬏
   ```

Step 1 is the part that replaces `apt-key`, but it doesn't seem possible to fetch individual GPG keys off of keyserver.ubuntu.com. Is it possible to adapt this approach for Ubuntu PPAs? If not, how can Ubuntu PPAs be added as software sources in Debian without the use of `apt-key`?

Answer (score 15):

`apt-key adv` basically passes CLI arguments/options directly to `gpg`, but only after setting up a temporary keyring. You can do the same manually with:

```bsh
$ export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"  # optional (skipping this means keys will be imported to your GPG keyring)
$ gpg --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 54B8C8AC
$ gpg --export 54B8C8AC | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/mkusb-archive-keyring.gpg
$ cat <<-SOURCE | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mkusb.list
    deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mkusb-archive-keyring.gpg] http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu focal main
    SOURCE
```

(`apt-key` is just a shell script, so you can examine the code yourself in your favorite editor; *e.g.,* `vim $(which apt-key)`.)

---

### If it's not working...

At first, I was receiving this error:

```
$ sudo apt update
...
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu focal InRelease [18.0 kB]
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E58A9D36647CAE7F
```

which turned out to be a file permissions issue:

```bsh
$ ls -l /usr/share/keyrings/*
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     3375 Nov 22 21:38 /usr/share/keyrings/filebot-archive-keyring.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1124 Nov 22 21:38 /usr/share/keyrings/mkusb-archive-keyring.gpg
-rw------- 1 root root     1126 Nov 29 08:15 /usr/share/keyrings/papirus-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Be sure you are saving developer GPG keys with `644` permissions.

---

### Another problem

From the `gpg(1)` manpage:

```
       --keyserver name
          This option is deprecated - please use the --keyserver in ‘dirmngr.conf’ instead.
```

Apparently the original approach has been **doubly** deprecated! AFAIK `gpg` does not issue warnings about the use of this CLI option (yet) but a proper solution to this problem would seem to look something like this?

```bsh
$ echo "keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com" >> "${GNUPGHOME}/dirmngr.conf"
$ gpgconf --kill dirmngr
$ gpg --recv-keys 54B8C8AC
...
```

except I tried this and got

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out
```

So if anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three options:

## apt-add-repository

The Debian package `software-properties-common` contains `apt-add-repository`.  Simply run `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:<user>/<ppa-name>` and it will add the repository to your APT sources and import the key.

## Get key from keyserver

Import the key into a separate keyring that you then move to the place where APT expects it:

```
$ echo "keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com" >> "${GNUPGHOME}/dirmngr.conf"
$ gpgconf --kill dirmngr
# I don't quite understand why this failed for you. Maybe a temporary network fluke or a firewall issue?
$ gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring=./papirus.gpg --recv-keys 54B8C8AC
$ sudo mv papirus.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
$ sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/papirus.gpg
$ sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/papirus.gpg
```

## Manually download key

If you cannot get the public key from a keyserver for whatever reason but you can download it manually, then import the downloaded file `papirus.pub` like this:

```
$ echo "keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com" >> "${GNUPGHOME}/dirmngr.conf"
$ gpgconf --kill dirmngr
$ gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring=./papirus.gpg --import ./papirus.pub
$ sudo mv papirus.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
$ sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/papirus.gpg
$ sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/papirus.gpg
```